# $$.getJSON, using a variable instead of a URL?

Tags: javascript, json, html-framework-7

I have **JSON** key/values saved in my localstorage.

**Localhost key/value store:**
[image]

I need to use **template7** to use the **handlebar style** tags in the code.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="navbar theme-green">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="left"><a href="index.html" class="back link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-back"></i></a></div>
            <div class="center">View Log Book</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block-title"></div>
    <div class="list-block">
       <ul>
          {{#each this}}
          <li>
             <a href="logdisplay.html" class="item-link item-content" data-context-name="logs.{{@index}}">
                <div class="item-inner">
                   <div class="item-title">{{rearcheckbox}}</div>
                </div>
             </a>
          </li>
          {{/each}}
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the JSON is in these key/value locally stored objects
and not in a file so when I need to use the code:

```
$$.getJSON('url', function (json) {
    myApp.template7Data.logs= json ;
});
```

I can't because it wants a URL and the JSON isn't in a file it's in localstorage.

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
myApp.template7Data.logs=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('2016-04-24'))
```

Comment: Thanks that helped :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse()` to parse JSON you have in a string.

jQuery's `getJSON` is just a wrapper around that and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Weirdly when i do this i get 'Cannot create property 'url_query' on string', is this just me being dumb or is this an issue with template7?

Comment: @hunterzzpro — Well, it has nothing to do with parsing the JSON.